# running IDA python without gui

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, idapython

I am trying to run IDA without GUI. My purpose is to run a specific script that receives arguments via my main program against multiple files, but for some reason, it does not work for me. Sometimes it opens IDA without any reason.

I am using the following commands:

One command is: `'C:\\IDA\\ida.exe -B %s' % file`

Second command is: `cmd = 'C:\\IDA\\ida.exe -a- -A -S"script.py "%s"" %s' % (file, file)`

Comment: How is IDA supposed to distinguish the script name from the parameter? You're using the exact same type of quotes (`"`) to denote two different things. You're attempting to quote the overall script+parameters, but you seem to also be quoting the parameter(s) with the same type of quotes. Not sure _how_ you execute this (i.e. which Python module), but `cmd.exe` is likely going to have an issue telling these apart ... not to mention that file names with blank spaces will garble up the whole thing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`ida.exe -A -S"<path\to\script> <params>" <path\to\file>`

`-A` - autonomous mode - no dialog boxes.

You can use `idat.exe` instead if `ida.exe`, which will not open the GUI of IDA.

You can end your script with:

```
from idc import *
idc.exit()
```

Which will exit the program when the script is finished.

You can see the complete list of command-line switches [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. after some tries(the script run) for some reason it does not rerun my scripts anymore. Do you know why ? I use the idat.exe as you said

Comment: Maybe your script fails/gets an exception and dies in certain cases?

Comment: No, nothing fail.

Comment: It's really hard to understand the issue without seeing the script. Another thing that you can do is to look in process monitor and see if instances are created and die, or it doesn't happen.

Comment: @DanielDan how do you know nothing fails? You gave us no indication that there is _any_ error checking involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your IDApython script in this format below:

```
from idautils import *
from idaapi import *
from idc import *
import os
autoWait() # to wait until ida analysis finished
f=open('result.log')#output result to a file
# your script here 
f.write('run script')
f.close()
exit() #close IDA after script finished
```

then use this command to run,you would see a GUI in a flash，Almost equivalent to no GUI.

```
./ida -A   -S"<path_to_your_script>" <path_of_binary>  -t
```

-A means auto run without interactive windows.

-t means make a temporary idb file.